# java object constructor returning null

Tags: java, intellij-idea

My Java object constructor is returning null for some reason. I'm running my constructor step-by-step in `intellij` IDE and the fields seem to be changing, but the value of `this` is still `null`.

I've included my code and an image link to the `null` message. I'm continuously getting despite successfully setting my local values to their appropriate initialising values.

```
public class DueDate {
Calendar cal;
Date deadline;

public DueDate() {
    deadline = new Date();
    cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
    System.out.println(cal.getTime());
    //this.deadline = cal.getTime();
}}
```

**call to the constructor:**

```
past = new DueDate();
```

[Screenshot of stepper during Constructor call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Glx6B.png)

Comment: How have you declared **past**? show that portion too.

Comment: The first thing called in constructor is `super` or `this` so your object is not null. As Naya says you have an object there.

Comment: @NikaNarushvili Not quite. Name "constructor" may suggest "creator", but that is not the case in Java since it doesn't take part in creation of object, it just modifies it *after* its creation. It is `new` keyword job to create an object. Problem is that fields of that object are set to default values: 0, false, null (depending on type) so we need some way to set it properly before anyone will be able to use it. And that is job of constructor.

Answer (score 1):

According to the screenshot the object already been created: 
as this = {DueDat@1427}

And "null" is the result of running toString() method. Please check it, the reason is there.

Answer (score -1):

I can see this is not null while debugging in IntelliJ.
[image]